# Excel formatting time as regular numbers

Tags: excel, timestamp

I've pasted into an excel file lots of number such as 43:11 or 22:06. These represent goals scored and goals against. However excel is recognising them as dates and times. I want it so that I have two columns with 43 and then 11 for example, instead of 43:11. Whatever I have tried it has become confused because it things of it as a time. I've tried formatting as text, numbers etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This will work in Excel 2016 (other versions have the same functionality but the menus may be slightly different):

1. Copy your numbers to the clipboard
2. In Excel, select the Home ribbon
3. Click the **downward arrow** under the `Paste` button (the leftmost icon on the ribbon).
4. Select `Use Text Import Wizard`
5. Wizard appears.  Make sure `Delimited` is checked and `My data has headers` is not checked.
6. Click `Next`.
7. In the `Delimiters` group, uncheck `Space`, check `Other` and in the box next to it type `:`
8. Click `Finish`

Comment: What version of excel has *Use Text Import Wizard* under Home, Paste?

Comment: Excel 2016 (Windows)

Comment: That's odd. My xl2016 has it in Data, Get & Transform Data, From Text/CSV or Data, Get & Transform Data, Get Data, From Text/CSV.

Comment: The key point is you have to copy the text data into the clipboard first (see step 1).  Otherwise when you click on the Paste arrow you get different options.

Comment: @OzSolomon I've seen that option on rare occasions. Thanks for clarifying the conditions under which it will appear!

Answer (score 1):

If you are typing values into a cell, then format the cell as *Text* before typing.  If you are importing material from an external source, then tell the Import Wizard that the field containing these values is *Text*.